# How to loop through data and make changes and save it to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a pattern such as below. `name` after segments increases by one every single time. So it would be 1, 2, 3, 4...100, 101 and so on. I am trying to change this numbers and keep the increasing by 1 pattern.

```
<segment name="0" start="0.0" end="6.6">
<orth>something</orth>
</segment>
<segment name="1" start="6.6" end="10.2">
<orth>something</orth>
</segment>
```

the full dataset has this pattern but I am just trying to change the `name` after `<segment`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<corpus name="corpus">
  <recording audio="audio01" name="name01">
    <segment name="0" start="2.98" end="3.67">
      <orth>sometext</orth>
</segment>
  </recording>
</corpus>
```

Here I try to set the starting number at `291199` and increase my way from there.

```
starting_num = 291199

with open('file.txt', 'r') as inputFile:
    w_file = inputFile.readlines()

w_file = w_file.strip('\n')

for line in w_file:
    if line.contains("<segment name"):
        //set name to starting_num
        starting_num = starting_num + 1
```

How would I be able to accomplish this task?

Comment: You can use something like ```lxml``` to parse the data as an lxml document, search for elements by segment/name\Or you can continue what your're doing, and ```split``` the string of the line to isolate the number. Either way convert the number to an ```int``, increment it how you want, and put it back in. If using lxml, you can just replace the name element. If doing it how you currently are, use ```replace``` and regex, or just replace segments individually using the output from ```split```.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
num = 291199

#opens and reads in the input file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as inputFile:
    #create a 2d array of each line in the list. Where each line has been split at the spaces
    w_file = [l.split() for l in inputFile.readlines()]

# create an empty list, that will store the data for the ouput file
output = []
#iterate through each line of the input file
for line in w_file:
    # check to see if we want to change this line
    if line[0] == "<segment":
        # update the new value of the line
        line[1] = (f"name=\"{num}\"")
        num += 1
    # add the line to the output list
    output.append(' '.join(line)+'\n')


# write the output list to an output file
with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as outputFile:
    outputFile.writelines(output)
```

This keeps the lines that do not start with `<segment` the same and changes those that should be incremented. The output is then written to a new file.